# Permission denied in cron jobs command

Tags: php, apache

I'm adding a new cronjob using the command command:

`/bin/sh: /home/gbtusyll/public_html/run.php`

But the command doesn't run and i get a mail stating:

> /bin/sh: /home/gbtusyll/public_html/run.php: Permission denied

What is the problem?

Answer (score 22):

Use `php /home/gbtusyll/public_html/run.php` instead to run it as a PHP script instead of a regular shell script.

Comment: Thnaks.For the first time i am using cronjob and it help me.

Comment: I am also new to cronjob. For new users, it should be noted that the link to your path to environment should also be properly mentioned in most cPanels like this `/usr/local/bin/php`, instead of just `php`. So use `/usr/local/bin/php /home/cPaneluser/public_html/yourscript.php`. Some cPanels with shared hosts may have different paths. `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` are popular paths from root. (Apparently, godaddy uses both, based on case.
 [(1)](https://in.godaddy.com/help/critical-paths-for-your-linux-vps-or-dedicated-server-1360) [(2)](https://in.godaddy.com/help/create-cron-jobs-16086) )

Comment: For most other hosts, [refer this guide to know more](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9453/29/how-to-run-scripts-via-cron-jobs)

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine. This might be checked as correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
chmod +x run.php
```

also ensure that proper owner is set (i.e. if you are logged as user, if the owner of the file is 'user' - you can do it for example by running `ls -la`

careful: this might be very dangerous on production evironment, however I believe this would solve your development problem. You should read more about permissions later on

Comment: For this to work you'll need to have a shebang line in your file; something like `#!/usr/bin/env php` as the first line.

Comment: @praseodym u are right, i upvoted your answer

Answer (score 2):

By itself, `/bin/sh` can't run php files. The PHP parses does that.
Using `/bin/sh` would only work if you give the file execute permissions (`+x`) and put `#!/usr/bin/php` (or wherever your PHP binary is located) as the first line of the file.

Try running `/usr/bin/php /home/gbtusyll/public_html/run.php` to use the PHP parser directly on your file. In this scenario, the PHP doesn't have to be executable to run.